# AuthStatus hook fail to authenticate user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, frontend, jsx

I want to create a private route component for my website via a PrivateRoutes component. See below

```
import React from "react"
import { Outlet, Navigate  } from "react-router-dom"
import {useAuthStatus} from '../../hooks/useAuthStatus'

const PrivateRoutes = () => {

    const {loggedIn, checkingStatus}  = useAuthStatus()

    return (loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' />)

}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

and a useAuthStatus hooks

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const useAuthStatus = () => {
  
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [checkingStatus, setCheckingStatus] = useState(true)
  
  const { userDetails } = useSelector(state =>state.userLogin)
  
    useEffect(() => {

      if (userDetails.status === "ok") {
        setLoggedIn(true)
      }

      setCheckingStatus(false)

    }, [userDetails])


  return { loggedIn, checkingStatus }

}
```

The state is stored on a redux userLogin container. I tested the application several times and i'm getting stuck checking the useAuthStatus hook.
If the login is successfull userDetails returns an object with a field status = "ok". I then check this value to set the loggedIn value to true.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (userDetails.status === "ok") {
        setLoggedIn(true)
 }
```

Unfortunately the logic is not working inside the useEffect hook, while perfectly working outside the useEffect. It looks like useEffect is firing before the userDetails gets populated (even if i set userDetails as a dependency of the userEffect hook to avoid getting an undefined object).

Please can you help me out?

Comment: Could you `console.log(userDetails)` in the `useEffect`?

Comment: Yes. This is what I get ---> console.log inside useEffect 
Object { status: "ok" }

Comment: It looks fine. Do you have maybe some minimal reproducible code sample for this issue? Like codesandbox?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I'm running the app locally. I am not a codesandbox user. Sorry